# Zend Framework 2: NotEmpty Validator Message

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework2

I'm having a form with an element `username`. There are two validators: `NotEmpty` and `StringLength`. The custom error messages for `StringLength` are working, but somehow it does not use the custom error message for the `NotEmpty` validator. In ZF1 the notEmpty validator was added automatically when making an element required which could be turned off. I can't find such an option in ZF2 and maybe my NotEmpty validator is not used because it was already added by the required flag!?

```
    $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
        'name'     => 'username',
        'required' => true,
        'filters'  => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'StringTrim'
            ),
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                'options' => array(
                    'messages' => array(
                        NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'Bitte geben Sie Ihren Benutzernamen ein.',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'StringLength',
                'options' => array(
                    'min' => 3,
                    'max' => 45,
                    'messages' => array(
                        StringLength::TOO_SHORT => 'Der Benutzername muss mindestens 3 Zeichene lang sein.',
                        StringLength::TOO_LONG => 'Der Benutzername darf maximal 45 Zeichen lang sein.',
                    )
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )));
```

Comment: First thing to do would be to `var_dump($form->getMessages())` to see what message key is actually used. Maybe the required message gets checked before the is_empty check and therefore you don't even reach the is_empty check. Check if `NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY` equals the message key from the output messages

Comment: @Sam, ofc it's the same key...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug in the version I was using. After updating to the latest revision on GitHub it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

The ZF2 Form, by default, adds validators for the different form elements automatically when creating them. To prevent the defaults from being added and only have your validators present, you need to add to the form constructor:

$this->setUseInputFilterDefaults(false);

This will prevent the Form object from adding those default validators. Now when you add your own NotEmpty, or any other element for that matter, validator with a custom message, that message is used instead of the default one.